# How to render 2-line address in lightning-formatted-address

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there a way to render 2 lines of address in the lightning-formatted-address component?  As someone who regularly has their email returned by the post office because either the apartment number is missing, or because it has been placed on the first line, I understand the need to display 2 lines above the city/state/zip.

I've tried using a formula field using '\n' or '\r' between the address lines but they are not translated into new line markup when the field is formatted in on the page.

Comment: Can you paste the lightning-formatted-address code ?

Comment: Have you tried with BR() in the formula?